# Border heading, paragraph and list in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to apply a border to a heading (Heading 2), a paragraph and a bullet list. I'd like all three elements to appear within one box however the list breaks the border into two distinctly bordered boxes.

Using a **single cell/row table** or an **inline text box** are not options because they cause the heading to no longer be listed in the navigation pane.

Any ideas?